# mysql search over two tables with some kind of inner join

Tags: mysql

table `estate_common` -> common data for estate as title name etc. estate could differ in kind
for example kind 1 - flat kind 2 - house etc.

```
id  | kind | title     | name
596 | 1    | title 596 | name 596
597 | 1    | title 597 | some 597
598 | 1    | title 598 | some 598
599 | 1    | title 599 | some 599
600 | 1    | title 600 | some 600
601 | 5    | title 607 | some 601
```

table `estate_kind_1` -> specific data for differnet kind each `estate_kind_#` has differnet structure columns etc.

```
id | estate_common_id | floor | flat | shell
1  | 596              | 250   | 9b   | pvc
2  | 597              | 156   | 10c  | abc
3  | 598              | 126   | 12a  | csd
4  | 599              | 226   | 2a   | add
5  | 600              | 198   | 15o  | fdd
```

`id` from `estate_common` is equal `estate_common_id` from `estate_kind_#` wherer `#` is number of `kind` from table `estate_common`

before preparing query i know that i must combine data from table estate_common and `estate_kind_1`

for simple detail of estate with data from both tables it´s easy

```
SELECT `common`.*, `kind`.* FROM `estate_common` AS `common` INNER JOIN `estate_kind_1` AS `kind` ON common.id = kind.estate_common_id WHERE (common.id = '597')
```

but now i start doing some xml export and need to select data from both table means `estate_common` and `estate_kind_1` upon selection of `estate_common id´s`

so query like this

```
SELECT `common`.*, `kind`.* FROM `estate_common` AS `common`, `estate_kind_1` AS `kind` WHERE (common.id IN ('596,597'))
```

but it gives me strange result

```
id  | kind | title     | name     | id | estate_common_id | floor | flat | shell
596 | 1    | title 596 | name 596 | 1  | 596              | 250   | 9b   | pvc
596 | 1    | title 596 | name 596 | 2  | 597              | 156   | 10c  | abc
```

data from table `estate_kind_1` means with id 1 a 2 on right side are ok but left from `estate_common` are for both lines same

should be

```
id   | kind | title     | name   | id | estate_common_id | floor | flat | shell
596  | 1    | title 596 | name 596 | 1  | 596              | 250   | 9b   | pvc
597  | 1    | title 597 | name 597 | 2  | 597              | 156   | 10c  | abc
```

i tried group by distinct etc. but probably in wrong way
will be glad for any help

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your latter query has no explicit `JOIN` so an `INNER JOIN` is being done. As there's also no `ON` clause, what's happening is a full cross product with a restriction on one table. The result you should be getting is that for every row of `kind` you will have two results - one for 596 of `common` and one for 597.

I assume you have cropped the result at 2 rows.

The query you want is:

```
SELECT `common`.*, `kind`.* 
  FROM `estate_common` AS `common`, `estate_kind_1` AS `kind` 
  ON common.id = kind.estate_common_id
  WHERE (common.id IN ('596,597'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I must be missing something about your question.  Is this what you want?

```
SELECT `common`.*, `kind`.*
FROM `estate_common` AS `common`
     INNER JOIN `estate_kind_1` AS `kind` ON common.id = kind.estate_common_id
WHERE common.id IN ('596,597')
```

Comment: SELECT `common`.*, `kind`.*FROM `estate_common` AS `common`     INNER JOIN `estate_kind_5` AS `kind` ON common.id = kind.estate_common_id WHERE (common.id IN ('596,597'))

as could be seen in last blokc of my question

gives just one row - with common.id 596
that was mi first idea.

i neadd to select 596 and 597 data from both table

Comment: in query shoud be estate_kind_1 instead estate_kind_5 as i posted few moments ago i just have different tables on my localhost

Answer (score 0):

solution is realy simple

```
SELECT common.*, kind.* FROM estate_common common, estate_kind_1 kind WHERE common.id = kind.estate_common_id AND (common.id IN (596,597))
```